# Yii: How to access related model object with limit

Tags: php, yii

I've two model class like A, B

**A and B both has relation defined in model class like:**

```
class A extends CActiveRecord {
  ...
  public function relations() {
    return array(
      'b' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'B', 'a_id'),
    );
  }
  ...
}

class B extends CActiveRecord {
  ...
  public function relations() {
    return array(
      'a' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'A', 'a_id'),
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

**Now I'm fetching all `A` using script:**

```
$a = A::model()->findAll();
```

**Then after I'm accessing all A's related object of `B`, but I want only limited records, like just 4 `B's` for each `A's`:**

```
foreach($a as $each_a) {
  $b = $each_a->b; // Want only 4 B's here
}
```

*How can I access only 4 B's records for each A's*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
change 
$bList = $a->b(array('limit',4));
to  
 $bList = $a->b(array('limit'=>4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a size parameter to the getter function.

Try the following:

```
$bList = $a->b(array('limit',4));
```

This should return 4 records. You can also add additional things like order to identify which 4 to get.